# Best practice for using React Redux new hooks?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm wondering what the best practice is for using React Redux's new hooks (https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks). For selectors, I know I can just do `useSelector(selectUser())` but I'm considering created a hook to wrap this:

```
// inside auth Slice
export const useUser = useSelector(selectUser());

// inside Profile.jsx
...
  const user = useUser();
...
```

This is a nice wrapper but I'm worried about performance hits (i.e. imagine using several of these hooks in the same component... each would call useSelector or useDispatch within their functions). Is this the best practice?

Comment: Check out [redux reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect), it has become a standard practice to have selector functions, often using reselect, and to feed those to `useSelector`.  No custom hook needed

Comment: it's perfectly fine. you can have thousand method calls like this without noticing any performance degradation